# En C. ¿Como se puede leer un numero con ceros a la izquierda?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){

int x;

scanf("%i",&x);              //Al ingresar el cero a la izquierda cambia 
                            // el 
                           //valor del numero, 
                          //por ejemplo si escribo 011.
printf("x es %i\n",x);    //x es 9 

system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Mi pregunta es si es una limitacion de C o existe alguna forma de no tener en cuenta los ceros a la izquierda al leer...

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información como que has probado o que has encontrado por Internet, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta con que cambies `"%i"` por `"%d"`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( ) {
  int x;
  scanf( "%d", &x );
  printf( "x es %i\n", x );

  return 0;
}
```

Si usas `%i`, `scanf( )` leerá **un entero**, interpretando los números que empiezan por `0` como números en base octal, y `0x` como base hexadecimal.

Usando `%d`, leerá **un decimal**, ignorando los 0 por la izquierda.